# how to show all playlist through php youtube api?

Tags: php, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am new to youtube api. I want to list all playlist according to a channel. Suppose, I have two channels. If I select any one of the channel then the associated playlists display as a link and when I click on that link, the associated videos are to be displayed.
Please help me, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Check out [YouTube API v2.0 – Searching for Playlists](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_playlist_search) and [Playlists : list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list) - maybe you can do something with this Google search: "inurl:http://www.youtube.com/playlist?"